# Laravel migration:rollback for pivot table giving class not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In a Laravel project, I have two models: User and UserRole, and corresponding tables: users and user_roles. I have a migration class "CreateUserUserRolePivotTable" for pivot table user_user_table. I have the appropriate belongsToMany relations in the User and UserRole models and the attach, detach, sync functions are working properly.

But when I try to execute -

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

Or -

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

I am getting the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Class 'CreateUserUserRolePivotTable' not found

I have tried using the model names in reverse in class - 'CreateUserRoleUserPivotTable' but I am getting the same error when rollback or reset.

Why is it happening and how to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `composer dumpauto` (or `composer dump-autoload`) to register migration, [you need to run this command after each created migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#running-migrations).

> If you receive a "class not found" error when running migrations, try
>   running the `composer dump-autoload` command and re-issuing the migrate
>   command.

Sometimes you need to run `composer dumpauto -o` to make it work.